# Move watermarked image to storage in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using Image intervention to apply watermark on uploaded image. But in order to increase the security, i want to move watermarked image to storage since i created symbolic link at storage. So far the watermark are applied successfully and it will store at a temporary file in public folder. But i cannot move the file to storage. Anyone know how to do it?

My code

```
$image = $request->file('image');
    $imageName = time().$image->getClientOriginalName();
    $image->move(public_path('temp'),$imageName);

    $img = Image::make(public_path('/temp/'. $imageName)); 
    $img->insert(public_path('watermark.png'), 'bottom', 10, 10); 
    $watermarked = $img->save(public_path('/temp/'. $imageName));

    // Here should move the file to storage but failed.
    $watermarked->move('public/users_image/personal/' . auth()->user()->id);



Identity::create([
        'image_name' => $imageName ,
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
    ]);
```